# Replace nested array for new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array inside another array:

Structure:

```
First Array
[
{
Second Array
   [
     {
     }
   ]
}
]
```

So I want to replace all Second Array for new array that I have so I try this:

```
this.FirstArray.map(
          (myArray) =>
            myArray.SecondArray === this.MyNewArray
        )
```

But this is not replacing for my new array it still having old values.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.FirstArray.map` returns a new array, which your code is discarding ... you also don't care about the `myArray` in each iteration, so, again, why are you using map at all - oops, you edited

Comment: could you create some variables with some meaningful content - rather than the very vague and very irrelevant and very invalid "Structure" you posted

Comment: If you are just replacing and know that index you can just `FirstArray[0] = [...newArray]`

Comment: There is a difference between `===`, `==` and `=`. In this case, you need `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using spread operator and without any loop as you want to replace second array with the new array.

Input array **:**

```
First Array
[{
  Second Array
   [{}]
}]
```

Logic to replace `newArray` with `secondArray` **:**

```
FirstArray[0].secondArray = [ ...newArray ]
```

Demo **:**

```js
const firstArray = [{
    secondArray: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
}];

const newArray = ['A', 'B'];

firstArray[0].secondArray = [ ...newArray ];

console.log(firstArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `map()` method will return a new array.

```
// Assume that your nested array looks like so:
let nestedArray = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["E", "F", "G"]
]

// Assume that this is the new array
const newArray = [1, 2, 3]

nestedArray = nestedArray.map(el => newArray);

// expected output: nestedArray [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```